# Does the script filter expression in JSONPath applies only to array elements (and not objects)?

Tags: jsonpath

I have gone through most of the JSONPath documentations out there and they all explain that the script filters such as `$.items[(@.length - 1)]` only applies to an array and not to a JSON object. This means that the path would work for the first JSON object below and not for the second one:

## 1:

```
{
  "items": [
     1,
     2
  ]
}
```

## 2:

```
{
  "items": {
     "item1": 1,
     "item2": 2
  }
}
```

Can anyone confirm this? Also, if I am correct, is there a logical reason for this behavior? I can imagine that such a path could have been allowed to return the same value (`2`) in both cases.