# JSONPath filter property by value in object

Tags: json, jsonpath

How can I use the JSONPath filtering capabilities to query for a specific condition on a property on a subobject (without an array)?

Consider this JSON example:

```
{
  "queue": {
    "size": 13
  }
}
```

I want to get a match if the `.queue.size` is greater than 0 and no match if it's equal to 0.
I tried using the following query but it does not work: `$.queue[?(@.size>0)]`. It is unclear to me why is that since the `$.queue[size]` does work returning value 13 correctly in this example, but if I include the filtering syntax I never get a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like JSONPath expressions applies only to arrays. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51548560/17139260) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232840/does-the-script-filter-expression-in-jsonpath-applies-only-to-array-elements-an). Your query `$.queue[?(@.size>0)]` works for:

```json
{
  "queue": [{
    "size": 13
  },
  {
    "size": 10
  }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the links. It looks like this is indeed not possible with current JSONPath but people are interested in adding it.

Answer (score 0):

a little trick could be:

$..queue[?(@.size>0)]

The only downside is that it will change every object in the subtrees if it matches the criteria. not only at the first level.